# How can I convert the day of the year (1-365) to its equivalent date (ie. January 5th, 2013) C++

Tags: c++, calendar

I've tried searching for an algorithm that could achieve this but haven't come up with any results.

I have the constructor Date2013(int dd).

In this member function I created an array with the months in it (January, February, Etc)

Then I created an if statement that takes in dd, if dd falls in between day 1 -31, then output January, if it falls between 32 - 59, then output February.

What I'm having trouble doing is, then taking the number they input, dd, and converting that to the appropriate day in the month. ie(The 34th day of the year is February 2nd).

Does anyone know of any algorithms or know of a way I could achieve this?

(I'm just beginning to learn my C++ so an explanation or comments in any code would be really helpful so that I can understand your thought process and syntax)

Comment: Convert `YEAR-01-01 00:00:00` to epoch. Add `(DAY - 1) * 3600 * 24` seconds, then convert back to date.

Comment: I would determine the timestamp of the first day of the year, and then add `(day-1) * 24 * 60 * 60` and convert that new timestamp to a date. That would give you a date in the format you want.

Comment: What have you tried so far - the reason I ask is to understand which approach you are taking, so that we can give you the "right kind" of answer.

Comment: with C look at struct tm and strftime to perform build a string with the format you want.

Comment: @syam Not good - there are leap seconds etc. that make that conversion inaccurate. I'd suggest instead to use some library that has built-in date operations. (If everything else fails, you could try doing it manually, i. e. calculating a leap year, having a vector of month lengths, etc., but that's not a real solid solution.)

Comment: @H2CO3 This is taken care of by the libc. As long as your timezone is known (ie. correctly configured on your system), you can convert to/from epoch seamlessly.

Comment: Isn't the 34th day of the year February 3rd rather than February 2nd, since there are 31 days in January?

Answer (score 6):

The most portable & reliable approach is to use the ANSI C mktime & localtime functions, which will work with either C or C++

**Update:**

To answer the question about how to implement your own algorithm rather than using standard C library mktime function, a good starting point would be to look at known-working code such as [the glibc mktime source code](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=time/mktime.c;hb=HEAD).  The relevant tidbits you would need include:

From [glibc 2.17 (HEAD) mktime.c](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=time/mktime.c;hb=HEAD) around line 141:

```
#define TM_YEAR_BASE 1900

/* Return 1 if YEAR + TM_YEAR_BASE is a leap year.  */
static inline int
leapyear (int year)
{
  /* Don't add YEAR to TM_YEAR_BASE, as that might overflow.
     Also, work even if YEAR is negative.  */
  return
    ((year & 3) == 0
     && (year % 100 != 0
         || ((year / 100) & 3) == (- (TM_YEAR_BASE / 100) & 3)));
}
```

From [glibc 2.17 (HEAD) mktime.c](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=time/mktime.c;hb=HEAD) starting at line 160:

```
const unsigned short int __mon_yday[2][13] =
{
    /* Normal years.  */
    { 0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334, 365 },
    /* Leap years.  */
    { 0, 31, 60, 91, 121, 152, 182, 213, 244, 274, 305, 335, 366 }
};
```

A sample C++ class implementing a constructor that converts year & dayOfYear to corresponding month & dayOfMonth might look something like:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define MONTHS_IN_YEAR 12

class MyDateClass {
public:
MyDateClass(int year, int dayOfYear) {
    int yearOffset = dayOfYear - TM_YEAR_BASE;
    int leapYearIndex = leapyear(year) ? 1 : 0;
    int daysInYear = leapYearIndex ? 366 : 365;

    this->year = year;
    this->dayOfYear = dayOfYear;

    if (dayOfYear >= 1 && dayOfYear <= daysInYear) {
        for (int mon = 0; mon < MONTHS_IN_YEAR; mon++) {
           if (dayOfYear <= __mon_yday[leapYearIndex][mon+1]) {
               month = mon + 1;
               dayOfMonth = dayOfYear - __mon_yday[leapYearIndex][mon];
               break;
           }
        }
    } else {
        cerr << "day of year must be between 1 and " << daysInYear << endl;
        month = 0;
        dayOfMonth = 0;
    }
}

// Get month 1=January, 12=December       
inline int getMonth() { return month; }

// Get day of month
inline int getDayOfMonth() { return dayOfMonth; }

// Get year
inline int getYear() { return year; }

// Get day of yar
inline int getDayOfYear() { return dayOfYear; }

private:
   int month;
   int dayOfMonth;
   int year;
   int dayOfYear;
};
```

Hopefully I won't get down-voted for showing sample code that might do the job.  Feel free to implement it however you want of course.  This is just one example approach.

---

*If you would rather use the existing mktime functionality (recommended), which should most likely be present in the standard C library on any platform you are programming, my original answer content follows...*

When using mktime you need to be sure to set tm_mon=0 and tm_mday to the day of the year ([see mktime documentation for a better explanation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/mktime/)), but in a nutshell mktime ignores tm_wday and tm_yday and only translates tm_mday, which it essentially interprets as the day of the year if you also set tm_mon = 0;

Here is some working sample code that illustrates the point, which will work in C or C++:

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, scanf */
#include <time.h>       /* time_t, struct tm, time, mktime */
#include <strings.h>    /* bzero */

int main () {
   time_t loctime;
   struct tm timeinfo, *loctimeinfo;
   int year, day;

   /* prompt user for year and day-of-the-year */
   printf ("Enter year: "); scanf ("%d",&year);
   printf ("Enter day of the year: "); scanf ("%d",&day);

   /* initialize timeinfo and modify it to the user's choice */
   bzero(&timeinfo, sizeof(struct tm));
   timeinfo.tm_isdst = -1;  /* Allow mktime to determine DST setting. */
   timeinfo.tm_mon   = 0;
   timeinfo.tm_mday = day;
   timeinfo.tm_year = year - 1900;

   loctime = mktime (&timeinfo);
   loctimeinfo = localtime(&loctime);

   printf ("The date for that day of the year is %s.\n", asctime(loctimeinfo));

   return 0;
}
```

Compile & sample runs:

```
$ g++ -o t2 t2.c
$ ./t2
Enter year: 2013
Enter day of the year: 1
The date for that day of the year is Tue Jan  1 00:00:00 2013

$ ./t2
Enter year: 2013
Enter day of the year: 365
The date for that day of the year is Tue Dec 31 00:00:00 2013
```

Even works for leap years like 2012:

```
$ ./t2
Enter year: 2012
Enter day of the year: 366
The date for that day of the year is Mon Dec 31 00:00:00 2012
```

Comment: @H2CO3 Funny, because that's pretty much what I said in my comment -- except I was too lazy to come up with a complete answer. ;) (+1 too, BTW)

Comment: Whilst I agree this is a good solution, I'm not convinced it teaches a beginner how to write code - I suspect the OP was looking to actually solve the problem using a small array/vector of days per month and calculating it - given the beginner status, doing that gives much more exercise in loops, arrays, etc, rather than filling in structs and calling library functions.

Comment: While I imagine this is a good example, @MatsPetersson is correct. I didn't even know the time class was a thing until this post. I was designing mine around arrays etc.

Comment: @PhDre/@Mats Petersson: updated my answer to include links & relevant excerpts from glibc's mktime.c source & sample C++ class to convert year/dayOfYear to month/dayOfMonth.  Sometimes I have trouble drawing the line between "teaching the man to fish" and teaching the man how to re-invent the fishing pole.  Hopefully my answer addresses both facets of your question: `(1)` Where to find/use an existing algorithm (mktime) and `(2)` how to go about implementing your own.  When in doubt, prefer to "stand on the shoulders of giants" and use the Standard C Library rather than home-growing your own.

Comment: @syam You suggested OP to do the math manually. In contrast, linguanerd uses the C standard library. There's a big difference :)

Comment: This is the most comprehensive and most helpful answer I have ever received, thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

So, the basic principle for CALCULATING this is to have a list of "number of days per month", and basically.

```
int days_in_month[13] = { 0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
```

If we then have a variable called `days` which is the number of days within the year and a `month` to indicate which month we end in:

Start with "month = 1;", simply check if the `days` is less than `days_in_month[month]`, and if it isn't subtract `days_in_month[month]` from days, and keep going until you either reach month = 12 and still have more days  and days is more than the `days_in_month[month]` [which means it's next year, start over with `month=1`, and move to next `year` - but I think your task is limited to 1-365 days, so just report an error is fine for now].

When the number of days isn't more than `days_in_month[month]`, you have the number of days into that month.

Note that I have intentionally *not* written the code for how to do this, but described how to do it. Because I'm the one who has written this sort of code at least a few times, and you are the one trying to learn. You do not learn by copying and pasting from SO.

Edit: And yes, I've completely ignored leap-years. For 2013, it's not a leap-year, so we don't care... ;)